# Bouncycastle S/MIME data headers

Tags: openssl, bouncycastle

Using Bouncycastle, is there anyway to stop it automatically adding in the "mandatory" headers to the data part? See below.  I understand that setting 7-bit is default if it is not specified, problem is the receiver of the message mandates just the original data. I can't strip them out (well I can) because they are part of the input to the signature generator.

```
------=_Part_1_1791323505.1516113283400
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

my message
------=_Part_1_1791323505.1516113283400
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: By "original data" do you mean the data without the S/MIME-part or do you mean the data with Content-Transfer-Encoding `binary`?

Comment: They wanted the smime structure but not those headers bouncy castle automatically puts in.

Comment: So what do they want the headers to be?

Comment: They don't want any! I'm not adding them, the library is doing it itself. Apparently the spec says that is fine

Comment: Openssl has a -t option to ignore header and output the data only...but they can't call that

Comment: OpenSSL isn't S/MIME, so I suppose what you want is the signed data as CMS? Is that correct? Also: Can you profide the code you use for signing? That would make it easier to answer this.

Comment: No worries, we had already fallen back to PEM format and that works fine between the two systems. FYI: Smime is supported by OpenSSL. As for code, it's just standard run of the mill signing code from any tutorial, all of them will see BC default the content headers and add them in. Therefore "changing" the data that is being signed. As the headers are included as part of the digest.

Comment: When setting up the builder for the signGenerator you can set a flag to get a single signature-block, not the multipart version. Maybe that's what would have helped. But since you found a working solution that's just a nice-to-know-thing ;-)